# How can I extract auth_token with the help of Jmeter?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, access-token

I need to make authentication. And I'm not able to get to auth. token to save it as a JMeter variable. How can I do it in my situation?

I'm attaching login process from Firebu and what I have in Jmeter. 
[FireBug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA2U5.png)

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwqa5onzktdxfbr/Jm.png?dl=0) My Jmeter.

Comment: It looks like a number of your variables aren't being set- the most obvious is `${Username}`, but I also see `{APPNAME}` in your JMeter results.

Comment: @RowlandB Don't look at it, this is the parts with old variables from another test...  `${Username}` is showing like this case I hardcoded it instead of creating that variable and `${APPNAME}` is just a part of url. My main problem is that i could get to auth token case there is other operetion after POST login. And to access them from Jmeter I need token.. (watch FireBug).